# Deploying an SSIS Package

Tags: ssis, package, deployment

I have a a project with multiple packages under the SSIS_Packages folder. Can i deploy one of those package instead of the project? The documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140117.aspx) indicates to use .SSISDeploymentManifest. I don't want to deploy all the packages under the project, just one to SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [dtutil utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162820%28SQL.90%29.aspx) out (following sample [taken from here](http://mgarner.wordpress.com/2006/08/31/automating-ssis-deployment/)) :

```
dtutil /DestS [servername] /FILE [filename].dtsx /COPY SQL;[foldername]\[filename]
```

Answer (score 0):

Easies would be to create a new SSIS project in VStudio containing only the desired package and deploy this single package.

Comment: This is what I've been doing but this is not the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just deploy a single package, you can also use the File -> Save Copy As ... functionality in BIDS:

1) Open package.
2) Click inside package whitespace to focus package.
3) In the BIDS menu, go to File -> Save Copy of  As ...
4) Fill in the pop-up box appropriately (Destination server name, authentication, package path on the server, protection level).

If you need to repeat this process, your best bet is to create a batch file that runs the dtutil executable with the appropriate command-line arguments.